# How to call stored procedure using HQL (Hibernate)?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to call a stored procedure written in postgres using Hibernate. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply run a `select your_function_name()`

Comment: Thanks.. It works